# What versions of Velocity does Spring4.x support?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, velocity

I know that Velocity is no longer supported in the latest Spring, but I need Velocity in my project. Therefore, I am trying to use Spring 4.x.
Can you please provide information on which versions of Velocity are supported by Spring 4.x?

Comment: Quote from git:
 "Velocity support package remains around in Spring Framework 4.3.x which we're maintaining until 2019"

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18368

Comment: There is native Spring Support in Velocity 2.3 which you should use instead of the Spring based support. That should work with newer versions as Spring as well. At least with 5.3. If you are stuck on 4.x you are able to use Freemarker 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring itself dropped support for Velocity in Spring 5.0, so Spring itself supports it upto Spring 4.3.x. In Spring 4.3 you can use Velocity 1.7, newer version might work but nothing is guaranteed.

There is also the `spring-velocity-support` package which aims at some Spring support. I'm not entirely sure what is in that.

Comment: Thanks for the info on Velocity 1.7 and 2.3. For some reason I need to use Velocity 1.6, do you know if there is support for this version? If you know of an official reference, please let me know. I have looked for hours on google but could not find it.

Comment: Spring itself has Velocity 1.7 as the dependency so that will be the minimal supported version. I strongly suggest to upgrade as 1.6 is even older then 1.7 and probably contains several bugs/security risks.